# Flash drive Partitions not showing in Amd64 Ubuntu 20.4 -but displays in Arm64 Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, mount, flash

I’m having difficulty accessing a USB flash drive on my Ubuntu 20.4 virtual machine.

I can access it on my Arm64 Ubuntu 18.4 Embedded computer. The blkid command reports /dev/sda2, along with the associated Label, UUID, Type=”ext4” and I can successfully mount this on this computer.

When I attempt the same on my virtual machine, all I get is

```
/dev/sdb: PTUUID="adb19fc3-b653-4d33-bd3a-f996422cfb5b" PTTYPE="gpt"
```

There are no partitions shown that I can mount. Are there commands I can run or packages that I can install that may help me mount this on my virtual machine?

For information, I am using VMWare for the virtual machine and it doesn't have any problem with other flash drives.

Comment: The `PTUUID` and `PTTYPE` fields make the output look more like that of `blkid --probe /dev/sda` than of plain `blkid`

Comment: No, its definitely a plain blkid command. I tried --probe also and this produced the same result, but when I run blkid command on my Arm64 platform it reports the partitions, and other details.

Comment: What about (as root) `blkid -c /dev/null` (non-root users may see out-of-date cached information)? As well, have you tried `lsblk`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. blkid -c /dev/null reports nothing. lsblk reports "sdb 8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk", which suggests it can detect the flash drive but not the partitions.